# Set iCal on Mac OS X to show a fortnightly view

Tags: macos, calendar, calendar.app

A week is too short, a month is too long. How can I setup iCal to show me a fortnightly (14 days) view?

I'll consider switching apps if that's necessary and unworkable in iCal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that iCal lacks this option, but Google Calendar can be configured for a "Custom View" of 2-7 days or 2-4 weeks if an online calendar is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

iCal doesn't that I know of, but [BusyCal](http://www.busymac.com) has the [option to display two weeks](http://www.busymac.com/help/userguide/view-prefs.html) in the Week View.  (Sadly, it's not free, although there's a 30-day time limited full functionality demo.)  It also has a number of other useful features.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the debug menu (which must be turned on in terminal.  See this link:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/apple/how-to-enable-icals-super-secret-debug-menu-and-14-day-weeks/12373

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Link-only answers are discouraged here on Super User (what if the link dies?). Please edit your question to summarize the procedure from the article.